# how to use Xquery to parse <![CDATA[ <DATA>; receive weird result

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I got a special XML format  . I got weird result after using xquery. the result is not a XML string. How to parse this XML format?

```
declare @xml xml

set @xml='<Data>
<![CDATA[ <DATA>
<NVPAIRS>
<PAIR><NAME>status</NAME><VALUE>100</VALUE></PAIR>
<PAIR><NAME>date</NAME><VALUE>20001224</VALUE></PAIR>
<PAIR><NAME>name</NAME><VALUE>Tom</VALUE></PAIR>

</NVPAIRS>
</DATA>
]]> 
</Data>
'



select x.query('.')
from @xml.nodes('//Data') as T(X)
```

the result i got:

```
<Data>
 &lt;DATA&gt;
&lt;NVPAIRS&gt;
&lt;PAIR&gt;&lt;NAME&gt;status&lt;/NAME&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;a&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/    PAIR&gt;
&lt;PAIR&gt;&lt;NAME&gt;date&lt;/NAME&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;20001224&lt;/VALUE&gt;    &lt;/PAIR&gt;
&lt;PAIR&gt;&lt;NAME&gt;&lt;/NAME&gt;&lt;VALUE&gt;12%3A30&lt;/VALUE&gt;&lt;/    PAIR&gt;

&lt;/NVPAIRS&gt;
&lt;/DATA&gt;

</Data>
```

Comment: This is the expeccted result -- content in CDATA tags is not XML content, but text, thus all angle brackets got quoted. You'll have to extract the textual content and parse it again somehow. A better alternative would be to explain the author of this broken XML that he'd better ship proper XML.

Comment: How do I extract the textual content and parse it by using Xquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you have to strip the non-xml from the beginning and end of your string before you can begin parsing. Here is an example of how you can do that with the sample you provided. You may need to tweak accordingly based on your actual XML data.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @String='<Data>
<![CDATA[ <DATA>
<NVPAIRS>
<PAIR><NAME>status</NAME><VALUE>100</VALUE></PAIR>
<PAIR><NAME>date</NAME><VALUE>20001224</VALUE></PAIR>
<PAIR><NAME>name</NAME><VALUE>Tom</VALUE></PAIR>
</NVPAIRS>
</DATA>
]]> 
</Data>
'

SET @XML = LEFT(RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - 17), CHARINDEX(']]>', RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - 17)) - 1)

SELECT @XML.query('/DATA')
```

You'll notice that you now have a valid XML object against which to query.